# iOS SQL Database access from Javascript

Tags: javascript, iphone, objective-c, sqlite, html

I am creating an iPhone/iPad app for the app store.  What I'd like to do is create it using HTML5/Javascript through a UIWebView so I can later use the HTML5/Javascript code for a web version as well (this is a requirement).  I would like to have an offline database (SQLite) that basically ships with the app - this would be the content for the app and the .sqlite file would exist in the /Supporting Files/ folder of my XCode Project.

My question is, how can I run queries and get data back from this database from Javascript?  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to build your own bridge or use one of the many HTML-based app frameworks available for iOS ([PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/), [Appcelerator](http://www.appcelerator.com/), etc).

If you want to go down the path of building your own bridge, you should check out `UIWebView`'s [`-stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIWebView), and the combination of `UIWebView`'s [`-loadRequest`](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIWebView) and `UIWebViewDelegate`'s [`webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIWebViewDelegate/webView%3ashouldStartLoadWithRequest%3anavigationType%3a) using a custom protocol (e.g., `com.mycompany.myapp.1.0://`) that you check for in the delegate method.

**EDIT:**

Here's some sample code:

Your HTML should have something like this:

```
<a href="myapp://doQuery?arg1=a&arg2=b">Do Query</a>
```

or:

```
<a href="#" onclick:"javascript:doQuery();">Do Query</a>
<script>
  function doQuery() {
    window.location = "myapp://doQuery";
  }
</script>
```

Then your webview delegate can capture a click there by:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)req (UIWebViewNavigationType)navType {
  if ([[req URL] scheme] == @"myapp:") {
    if ([[req URL] host] == @"doQuery") {
      // Do the query here.
      [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"latestResult = %@; queryReturned(latestResult);", queryResultAsJSON]];
    } else if ([[req URL] host] == @"doSomethingElse") {
      // Do something else.
    }
    return NO;
  }
  return YES;
}
```

Comment: This helps - although I'm not sure what it means to build my own bridge - and I don't mind doing that if I can get some level of customization out of it.  Do you have a link for a tutorial or anything that better explains this?  Also, do you know for sure that I can run a query and get that data into Javascript layer as called for BY the Javascript?